# Is there a way to debug an android application visually

Tags: android, android-studio

It happens that an old Android project was assigned to me to add new functionalities. I´m relatively new to Android and I don´t know where to start. So the question is if there is like a visual debugger? What I mean is: in a more humanly possible manner, is there a way to see which data is being transfered from fragment to fragment, intent to intent, when I click a button what is going on under the hood? When are REST Apis being called... etc... Is there a tool that could achieve in Android? If there is not, what could I do to jump in a new project and know what is all about. This is a wallet project with payments, card enrollments, SSL certificates, API calls, and more.

Thanks in advance